# Accessing json API, custom accept type madness

Tags: json, api, get, url-parameters

I'm trying to make a request to this API:

http://services.vrt.be/epg/playlists

Default it returns text/html.

when i query it in a browser like this:
http://services.vrt.be/epg/playlists?accept=text/html it still returns the html as requested.

But when i query it like this:
http://services.vrt.be/epg/playlists?accept=application/vnd.epg.vrt.be.playlists_1.0+json

With the right datatype as stated in the APIs doc it 406's and tells me it's not acceptable.

the error page shows a list of accept types like this:

> The following media types are supported: application/vnd.epg.vrt.be.playlists_1.0+xml, application/vnd.epg.vrt.be.playlists_1.0+json, application/vnd.epg.vrt.be.playlists_1.1+xml, application/vnd.epg.vrt.be.playlists_1.1+json, text/html

Wich lists the accepttype i provided. What am i doing wrong, am i passing it correctly? (the accept parameter is defined by the doc and works when provided ith the text/html type)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These URLs seem to work (at least they don't error out):

```
http://services.vrt.be/epg/playlists?vnd.epg.vrt.be.playlists_1.1+json
http://services.vrt.be/epg/playlists?vnd.epg.vrt.be.playlists_1.0+xml
```